# Can not deleting the cells from a segment of tableview in swift ios

Tags: ios, swift, if-statement

I have 4 `segments` in `tableview` but when I am trying to delete the cell of specific segment in tableview, but the loops does not enter in the segment because it does not printed the specific prints statements.
When I press the delete by swift it prints "delete" and "nothing changed", I think loop does not enters in segments.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    print("delete")

    if editingStyle == .delete {
        print("delete")

        if selectedContact == 1 {
            print("trying to delete from segement one")
            wInstockArray.remove(at: indexPath.row)
            firstTableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .fade)
            firstTableView.reloadData()
        }

        else if selectedSegment == 2 {
            print("trying to delete from segement two")
            wCheckinArray.remove(at: indexPath.row)
            firstTableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .fade)
            firstTableView.reloadData()
        }

        else if selectedSegment == 3 {
            print("trying to delete from segement three")
            wInspectionArray.remove(at: indexPath.row)
            firstTableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .fade)
            firstTableView.reloadData()
        }

        else if selectedSegment == 4 {
            print("trying to delete from segement four")
            wCheckoutArray.remove(at: indexPath.row)
            firstTableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .fade)
            firstTableView.reloadData()
        }

        else {
            print("nothing changed")
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: remove `reloadData` if you are using `firstTableView.deleteRows()` you don't need `firstTableView.reloadData()`, check if "trying to delete from segement one" is printed?

Comment: Add a breakpoint before your if statements and see what selectedSegment is returning.  I notice on your first condition you are using `selectedContact` whilst the others show `selectedSegment` ?

Comment: check if you're getting valid value for "selectedSegment" or "selectedContact".

Comment: @iOSDeveloper Was that the problem ?

Comment: I mistakenly put selectedContact instead of selectedSegment :)

Comment: Updated as the answer then.  Happy coding :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first condition in the `if-statement`, tests `selectedContact`, instead of `selectedSegment`.